# Linked Server - Access to the remote server is denied

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have combed the web in search for an answer for the error returned from Sql Server Agent Job running against a remote database and yet could not get it to work. The error is:

```
    Msg 15274, Sev 16, State 1, Line 1 : 
    Access to the remote server is denied because the current security context is not trusted. [SQLSTATE 42000]
```

I had linked the server set up like so:

```
    EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server=N'serverName' 
       , @srvproduct=N''
       , @provider=N'SQLNCLI'
       , @datasrc=N'serverName';
```

And equally ran:

```
    EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin  @rmtsrvname = N'serverName'
       , @useself = false
       , @locallogin = NULL
       , @rmtuser = 'sa'
       , @rmtpassword = 'userpassword'
```

When I execute `EXEC  [ServerName].[DbName].[SchemaName].[StoredProcName]`I get values returned successfull but same query failed in Sql Agent Job. What must I do to get Agent Job to work?

Comment: It yould be that your Agent is running under the account with not enough privileges to access the linked server. Which acc is the agent running under?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/811031).

In short, it seems that this happens:

> When you run a SQL Server Agent job that is not owned by a system
>   administrator account, SQL Server Agent runs SETUSER to impersonate
>   the owner of the job.
>
> If the job uses linked servers, the job may fail because remote access
>   is not allowed after the execution of SETUSER.

So, either you change ownership of the job to sysadmin acc, or change your linked server mapping to e.g. use impersonation. I don't see any other option.

Comment: Thanks Ozren. I am setting up a Credential after which I will set up a Proxy. Or how do I change ownership of the job to sysadmin? Thank you

Comment: SSMS: Go to object Explorer, expand SQL Server Agent, expand Jobs. Find your job, right click, select Properties. Change user by editing Owner field. Use sa (if you can) or some other user with sysadmin role.